# Does every graph arise as the commutativity graph of some group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

By *graph* let us mean a set $G$ together with a relation $\bot$ that is reflexive and symmetric. Now every **group** gives rise to a *commutativity graph* by defining $x \,\bot\, y \iff xy=yx.$

Does every graph arise as the commutativity graph of some group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For any prime $p$, the only group of order $p$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is abelian. Therefore, the only graph on $p$ vertices that is a commutativity graph is the complete graph.

Comment: Ah of course. I seem to be asking a lot of silly questions of late :(